# How to run kafka listener and jms listener parallely in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-jms, spring-kafka

In  my application i have @kafkalistener and @jmslistener in diff class , when i run my program jms listener consuming the data first, i want do  run parallely.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topicName", groupId = "foo")
public void listen(String message) {
    System.out.println("Received Messasge in group foo: " + message);
}
```

jms code

```
@JmsListener(destination = AppConfig.QUEUE_NAME)
  public void handleMessage(String message) {//implicit message type conversion
      System.out.println("received: "+message);
```

Comment: Set offset to earliest and try

Comment: @Deadpool  it's not based on offset.

Comment: Then what is the problem?

Comment: @Deadpool Kafka listener and jms listener need to run parallely it's a two diff component

Comment: They are fully not related. Each of them is handled in its own listener container with their own thread management. So, that is clear coincident that JMS has started first.

Comment: @ArtemBilan but I need to run Kafka listener first when jms listener queue received any data then only it needs to run !!

Comment: How are they related? Both of them are streaming components and they are fully independent. What is the business purpose to wait for Kafka client to poll something? That would be great to have in your question as an explanation “why?”. It is just a fact that JMS reacts to the messages in the queue faster in the beginning because it doesn’t need a rebalance like Kafka. Anyway it’s just fully feels like some misunderstanding how consumers work in streaming scenarios...